# Where to put super.init() when init() also initializes member variable and references "self"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

I'm learning Swift, and I now have this code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class Player: GKEntity {

var spriteComponent : SpriteComponent

init(imageName: String) {
    super.init() // gives error: self.spriteComponent not initialized at super.init call
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:  imageName)
    spriteComponent = SpriteComponent(entity: self, texture: texture, size:  texture.size())

    // super.init() Placing it here gives error on line above: "self used before super.init() call"
    addComponent(spriteComponent)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

I have seen other questions about this, but I can't imagine that I would have to create a dummy initializer (with zero args) in SpriteComponent and call that like:

```
var spriteComponent = SpriteComponent()
```

in order to call super.init() before referencing "self"

Can anyone explain why I have to do this idiotic tap-dancing?  There surely must be a better way to do it right? Swift can't be that *&%&/(% right?

Comment: try using `var spriteComponent : SpriteComponent!` instead

Comment: OK it seems there are solutions to this then. Coming from Java/C# etc I was used to variables initialized to null if not otherwise specified. I can live with initializing it to nil myself. I'm still not confortable with all the ? and !'s in Swift..

Comment: @PeterAnderson the ! and ? notation is quite simple once you get the hang of it, so if a variable doesnt have any, that means it cant be nil at all, so basically it cant have an empty value to start with. `!` means is can be empty to start with, but once its assigned it can never be nil again (and if you try to access it while its still initially nil the app will crash), `?` is basically like a normal java variable where anything goes, but before you can access it you must always "unwrap" it which basically means making sure its not nil before using it eg `if let x = OptionalVariable`

Comment: or `optionalVariabe?.someMethod()` (`someMethod()` wont execute if `optionalVariable` is nil, this is a sort of short hand null check which is the great part about this optional stuff)

Comment: OK thx for explaining. But accessing a member `var node : EntityNode!` that is later constructed in `init()` still gives me  `"Value of optional type 'EntityNode?" not unwrapped;..."`

Comment: hmm are you trying to go `var x = node?.something()`? or something similar? the type that is returned from that will always be optional, so if you use `x` its type is `EntityNode?` instead of `EntityNode!` you should just go `var x = node.something()` because you dont need to test if `EntityNode!` is nil or not (if it is nil, the flow of your program is a bit wonky, you can still test it for nil if you really need to though)

Comment: Again, thx for trying to help, but I'm following a tutorial, and its not exactly great OO-wise (accessing variables in other classes directly etc). It seems like there are issues with the tutorial that confuses me, and this comment area is not the proper place for a lengthy (I'm sure) discussion about my specific problem. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize all non-optional properties declared in your subclass before you can call super.init()

So you have two ways of solving such issues:

1. Change property type to optional (either `SpriteComponent?` or `SpriteComponent!`).
2. Initialize every property either when you declare it or in your initializer before calling super.init

In your case first option suits better.

You can find more info about Swift two-phase initialization here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html

This tutorial may also be helpful: (*Adding Properties to Subclasses* paragraph):
https://www.raywenderlich.com/121603/swift-tutorial-initialization-part-2

Answer (score 1):

All the non-optional properties must be initialised before the object is created. Make your property an optional.

Answer (score 1):

`spriteComponent` is a non-optional var. Therefore it has to be initialised before calling `super.init` (explains the 1st mentioned error).

You can not solve this by calling `super.init` later, because the constructor of `SpriteComponent` needs a reference to self, which is only available after calling `super.init`. (explains the second error)

As a solution you can make `spriteComponent` an unwrapped optional:

```
var spriteComponent : SpriteComponent!
```

This instructs the compiler to allow `spriteComponent` not to be initialised, and gives you the responsibility do do it yourself at a later point in time.

Answer (score 1):

This "Tap-Dancing" has a reason.
In swift, class initialization is a two-phase-initializtion :

Phase #1 - All stored properties are given some initial value (nil is also fine) by the class that defined them

Phase #2 - Now each class may change the initial value and use self

Why is that? Safety mainly - knowing in phase #2 that all properties has some values.

Therefore, in your code, you may not need an empty dummy initializer, but turning your sprite component to an optional could be handy :

```
class Player: GKEntity{
var spriteComponent : SpriteComponent? = nil  // optional

init(imageName: String)
{
    super.init() // now OK

    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:  imageName)
    spriteComponent = SpriteComponent(entity: self, texture: texture, size:  texture.size())!
    addComponent(spriteComponent!)  // unwrap here
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}